# How can I load a quote by session ID?

Tags: magento-1.7, session

If have the frontend session ID, how can I load the quote associated with that?

Answer (score 6):

You'd need to close the current session and reopen a new session with the given session id `$id`:

```
// instantiate session model first
$session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');

// close session. the session model does not provide a method for this
session_write_close();
unset($_SESSION);

// open new session
$session->setSessionId($id);
$session->init('checkout', 'frontend');
```

Now you can retrieve the quote as usual:

```
$session->getQuote();
```

If you want to restore your own session afterwards, you have to close the session again and reinitialize the session model with the original session id:

```
session_write_close();
unset($_SESSION);
$session->setId($_COOKIE['frontend']);
$session->init('checkout', 'frontend');
```

Instead of retrieving the original id from the cookie, you can also back it up first with `$session->getSessionId()`, which will be more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

To set a Id in session object you can use this:

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
$session->setSessionId('ID_SESSION_HASH');
/* @return Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien */
```

I don't know if it's works, but I think it just set the Id in current session. There is no load method in Mage_Core_Model_Session or parents classes and there is no association in Quote Model with the session id.

setSessionId uses session_id function in Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien

To get Quote from session:

```
$quote = $session->getQuote();
```

Comment: This does not reload the session, so it only works if the session has not been started yet. Unfortunately the session is started in the constructor of the session model, so no matter how early you call this code, the session will already be initialized.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28545984/magento-api-how-to-load-customer-session-by-id

`Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('value' => $session_id))->getQuote();`

Comment: Good catch with the 'value' parameter, but it will only work if the session is not initialized yet.

Comment: Sorry I'm guessing you'd need to use `getModel` in this instance.

Comment: Still does not help because the constructor doesn't do anything if a session is active: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php#L221-L223 (even without this check, `session_start()` would fail)

Comment: Ah yeah nice spot.

Answer (score 0):

Was there ever any resolution to this by anyone? Trying to load a quote by Session ID or Session Data?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/204079)